# Plotly: How to show only today's data on a figure?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, plotly

I have made a graph using time axis on the X axis, however I want to show only today's data. (i.e restrict the date to current date)

Here is the code I used to produce those graphs :

```
fig = go.Figure()
fig = make_subplots(rows=2,cols=1,shared_xaxes=True,vertical_spacing=0.02)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data['time'],y=data['x_last_recorded'],name='xyz',mode='lines+markers'),row=2,col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=predict_data['time'],y=predict_data['x1_last_recorded'],name='x1yz',mode='lines'),row=2,col=1)

fig.update_layout(height=800,width=1500,title='first_graph',yaxis_title='Values')
```

This has got me a graph of how I want, but it is showing all the dates present in the dataframe. How do I fetch only the current date's data?
Structure of time : dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can solve your challenge by subsetting your dataframe using an approach such as `df_current = df[df.index.date==df.index.date[-1]]`, and then restyle your figure by letting different subsets be represented by different options in a dropdown menu.

Here's the resulting figure for the different subsets / selection options:

#### All dates

[image]

#### Current date

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
# imports
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# sample data in the form of an hourlt
np.random.seed(1234)
tseries = pd.date_range("01.01.2020", "01.04.2020", freq="H")
data = np.random.randint(-10, 12, size=(len(tseries), 2))
df = pd.DataFrame(index=tseries, data=data)
df.drop(df.tail(1).index,inplace=True)
df.columns=list('AB')
df.iloc[0]=0
df=df.cumsum()

# subset method
df_current = df[df.index.date==df.index.date[-1]]

# plotly setup
fig = go.Figure()

# set up a trace for each column in a dataframe
for col in df.columns:
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index, y =df[col], name=col))

# container for updatemenus and buttons
updatemenu = []
buttons = []

# button 1
buttons.append(dict(method='restyle',
                    label='All',
                    visible=True,
                    args=[{'y':[df[col].values for col in df.columns],
                           'x':[df.index],
                           'type':'scatter'}, ],))
# button 2
buttons.append(dict(method='restyle',
                    label='Current',
                    visible=True,
                    args=[{'y':[df_current[col].values for col in df_current.columns],
                           'x':[df_current.index],
                           'type':'scatter'}, ],))

# menu setup
your_menu = dict()
updatemenu.append(your_menu)

updatemenu.append(your_menu)
updatemenu[0]['buttons'] = buttons
updatemenu[0]['direction'] = 'down'
updatemenu[0]['showactive'] = True

# add dropdown menus to the figure
fig.update_layout(showlegend=False, updatemenus=updatemenu)
fig.show()
```

Comment: This is a great idea @vestland. I will give this a shot and tick your answer :) Thank you for your help!!